# pdflatex -no-parse-first-line not ignoring first line

Tags: compiling

I want to be able to compile my documents with a simple `./main.tex`. The first thing I tried was `#!/usr/bin/pdflatex` which gave me an error because the first line is nonsense to the TeX engine. I then tried it with a `%` instead but that, as expected didn't do much of anything.

Looking this problem up online I tried adding `-no-parse-first-line` to the shebang, but again no luck. Then I thought "executing a script defaults to `/usr/bin/sh` so why not just use a normal line". To this end I put `pdflatex -no-parse-first-line $0` as my first line, but that doesn't work either.

```
$ ./main.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 p
     dflatex -no-parse-first-line $0
?
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, that would explain it. If you'd write that up as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: OK, converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the web2c documentation, which is the "real" documentation, `-no-parse-first-line` checks or disables checking whether the first line of the main input file starts with `%&`, and parse it if it does. This line can be used specify the format and/or a TCX file. So I think that the unix man page for pdflatex is misleading as it only ignores "certain" first lines.